# Jhipster Deployment to Cloud Foundary throwing UnexpectedLiquibaseException

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, jhipster

I am trying to deploy my Jhipster app to Cloud Foundry. After the cf push of the war file the status goes to flaps. This error is in the log:

```
ERR Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.net.UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support input
```

Google told me this problem is reported and solved here

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1792

But it doesnt tell me how to implement any resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug with CloudFoundry/Spring Boot/Liquibase.
This is solved in our latest version.

Comment: Good to hear it is fixed. I have updated JHipster using npm update -g generator-jhipster and updated the project pom to use boot-starter-parent <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version> (from 1.1.8) and that has not helped. What else should I be doing?

Comment: I see, the fix is in Application.java. Thanks